# Invocable Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, apexrest

I'm trying to write test class for one of the Invocable class that calls another class, though the test passes but i don't think it is actually testing the code. Struggling to call list in test class

```
public class RadarSafetyEvent {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Radar')
    public Static void CallRadar(List<Patient_Event__c> SE) { 
        
        if(SE[0].Campus_where_event_occurred__c=='RUMC'){
            RadarUpdate.PatientEventRUMC(SE[0].Id);
            SE[0].put('Sent_to_Radar1__c', TRUE);
            update SE;
        }
        else if(SE[0].Campus_where_event_occurred__c=='ROPH'){
           RadarUpdate.PatientEventROPH(SE[0].id);
            SE[0].put('Sent_to_Radar1__c', TRUE);
            update SE;
        }
        else{ 
           update SE;
        }      
    
    }
}
```

```
@isTest
public class RadarSafetyEventTest {
@isTest  static void CallRadarTest(){
    
        rkl__Form_Template__c peft = new rkl__Form_Template__c(Name='Initial Reported Patient Event');
        insert peft;
        
        Patient_Event__c  SE = new Patient_Event__c();
        SE.Patient_First_Name__c='Patient First Name';
        SE.Patient_Last_Name__c='Patient Last Name';
        SE.Type_of_Event__c = 'Privacy/Confidentiality';
        SE.Type__c ='Incident';
        SE.Patient_Med_Rec_Num__c= '123456';
        DateTime dt = system.Now();
        SE.Campus_where_event_occurred__c ='RUMC';
        SE.Date_Time_of_Event__c= dt.date();
        SE.Event_Description__c= 'Testing Privacy office';
        SE.Privacy_Confidentiality_Category__c='Identity misuse/theft';
        insert SE;
   
   
        List <Patient_Event__c> SEevent = new list<Patient_Event__c>();
         SEevent[0].put('Sent_to_Radar1__c', TRUE);
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHTTPResponseGenerator()); 
         update SEevent;
   
 
             
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While there is a great deal of missing information here (how is this code invoked? what is the other invocable method?), there is one clear problem:

The test data you are generating does not match the entry expectations for two of your branches. You create a record

```
    List <Patient_Event__c> SEevent = new list<Patient_Event__c>();
     SEevent[0].put('Sent_to_Radar1__c', TRUE);
```

but your code expects `Campus_where_event_occurred__c` to be populated with one of two non-`null` values. The `else` case (if that field matches neither arm) does nothing at all:

```
    else{ 
       update SE;
    }
```

That means the two `if` statements that take action will never be executed.

Your code needs to generate data that exercises specific code paths and then validates that the outcome is what is expected. Right now, the test data you're generating appears to already set `Sent_to_Radar1__c` to `true`, which is probably also incorrect and will prevent you from writing a *meaningful assertion* that your code is operating as designed.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why Campus_where_event_occurred__c is not being recognized when i already added it while inserting the test data.